# Issue about connecting with WalletConnect by using the example of Web3Modal

Tags: web3js, walletconnect

I have tried to run the example of Web3Modal on my local env, and then use IMToken to scan the QRcode showed by clicking the WalletConnect, but at last I just got an error which is showing below:

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/6203602/94316022-31a13280-ffb6-11ea-9ec0-46cba91205a9.png]

Please suggest me a possible solution about this issue and please let me know what else code you want me to provide, thanks!

BTW, I have tried using different infuraId to init Web3, but got same error, even if I used the id from live demo site of web3modal

[Example link](https://github.com/Web3Modal/web3modal/tree/master/example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered the same issue. It's a known bug in web3.js v1.3.0 that was brought in this PR: [#3649](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/pull/3649). In this [comment](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/pull/3649#issuecomment-695200876) someone explains it in more detail.

There is an ongoing PR [here](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/pull/3721) that will fix it, so i'd suggest to keep an eye on that one.

A temporary solution would be to downgrade to web3 v1.2.11